# How do I clear content in rows based on cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I copy a lot of information (1000 rows and at least 24 columns) from one sheet to another. A lot of the cells contains "". This makes my other formulas(for example: A1-B1) to show an value error if either of these cells contains "". 
I believe I can solve the problem by never pasting "" but a "0" instead. But I would like to delete these "0" afterwards.

There could be values in the first 3 rows but the other 997 rows have "".

I would think I need to tell my macro to (Cell A1 in the "sheet1" sheet displays "G5:H12". the cells I need to delete):

```
Rowstodelete = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1").Value

Sheets("sheet1").Range("rowstodelete").clearcontent
```

This does not work. anyone know how to do this?

Summary(new example)

If cell A1 = "B1:B2" I want to clear the content of B1 and B2, but if A1 now = B4:B6, that is the cells that should be cleared.

Comment: If you put 0 and then clear them, you will have the same problem all over again, errors in your formulas. Or will you copy & paste values?

Comment: Example: A1 and B1 are empty (or rather contains ""), C1 has a formula like A1-B1. 

C1 shows a value error after I pasted "" in both A1 and B1. When I then manually put a 0 in A1 and B1 then deleting them. so both of the cells are now empty. I do not get the value error anymore.(this has nothing to do with refreashing with F9)

Comment: The only possible logic(?) in changing empty string to zero and make reverse operation is 1) when you won't change your formulas 2) empty string means something different from zero (e.g. empty string "" = no value read, 0 means - value is zero). Is this true? If not, your approach is wrong and loops (as presented in below answers) are not necessary and slow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
With Worksheets(1).Range( _'PLACE YOUR RANGE
                                            ) 
    Set c = .Find(0, lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = c.Address 
        Do 
           c.Value = "" 
            Set c = .FindNext(c) 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If 
End With
```

Hope it helps

Anyhow, I think that will be simpler to place a condition in your operation formula: `=IF(OR(A1="",B1=""),Make when there is an unexpected value,A1-B1)`